# Device initialization failed - Android

Tags: android, initialization, device

I am trying to run an Application on an Iball TABLET , every time i plug that TAB with my PC.These errors show up

```
01-01 08:53:15.320 875-885/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
01-01 08:53:15.321 665-665/? E/MtkAgps: [MtkAgpsManagerService][agps] ERR: imsi=null is invalid on SIM=1 
01-01 08:53:15.341 875-1282/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
01-01 08:53:15.348 665-665/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
01-01 08:53:15.349 665-665/? E/MtkAgps: [MtkAgpsManagerService][agps] ERR: invalid mccMnc= on SIM=1 
01-01 08:53:15.368 3547-3547/? E/st480d: Senodia : open error.
01-01 08:53:15.368 3547-3547/? E/st480d: Senodia : Device initialization failed!
01-01 08:53:15.374 875-1282/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
01-01 08:53:20.837 3550-3550/? E/st480d: Senodia : open error.
01-01 08:53:20.837 3550-3550/? E/st480d: Senodia : Device initialization failed!
01-01 08:53:22.022 3430-3471/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x64ec7728 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x6135b8b8 arg=0x0
01-01 08:53:22.022 3430-3471/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x64ec7728 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
01-01 08:53:25.841 3552-3552/? E/st480d: Senodia : open error.
01-01 08:53:25.842 3552-3552/? E/st480d: Senodia : Device initialization failed!
01-01 08:53:30.846 3553-3553/? E/st480d: Senodia : open error.
01-01 08:53:30.846 3553-3553/? E/st480d: Senodia : Device initialization failed!
01-01 08:53:35.850 3566-3566/? E/st480d: Senodia : open error.
```

The same application is running fine on Samsung Galaxy TAB.But in Iball TAB it misbehaves.